# The action of vectors on one forms

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors, differential-forms

I have searched the web for an answer to this question but couldn't quite find what I was looking for.

Given a Manifold $M$ and a choice of local coordinates $\lbrace{x}^{i}\rbrace$ one can give the expression for a tangent vector $V \in {T}_{p}M$ in these local coordinates as

$$V={V}^{i} {\partial}_{i}$$

Now a vector can be defined as a linear operator from smooth functions on $M$ to the reals, i.e. ${C}^{\infty} \left( M \right) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and this is a concept I am completely fine with, however my trouble comes when considering the action of Vectors on one forms.

Take a one form in the same coordinate system 
$$\omega = {\omega}_{i} d{x}^{i}$$
where ${\omega}_{i} \in {C}^{\infty} \left( M \right)$ then what is the action of the vector on this one form? Is it defined? I know that from the usual construction of one forms as elements of the dual space of ${T}^{*}_{p}M$ allows us to think of one forms as $\mathbb{R}$-linear maps ${T}_{p}M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the following relation between the dual basis elements 
$$ d{x}^{i} \left( {\partial}_{j} \right) = \frac{\partial {x}^{i}}{\partial {x}^{j}}= {{\delta}^{i}}_{j}$$
Where the action of the basis element on an arbitrary vector 
$$d{x}^{i} \left( V \right) = {V}^{j} \frac{\partial {x}^{i}}{\partial {x}^{j}}={V}^{i}$$
Which is just the directional derivative of the $i$th coordinate function along $V$ and so this gives us our action

$$ \omega \left( V \right) = {\omega}_{i} d{x}^{i} \left( V \right) = {\omega}_{i}{V}^{i}$$
Is there a well defined action for $V \left( \omega \right)$? If not is there a reason why this action is not well defined and thus can't be constructed? My apprehension is derived from the fact the basis elements of $T_{p}M$ are differential operators and naturally obey a Leibniz law.

Thanks for reading and any responses will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Rather than "action", it's better to think of it as a "pairing": $T_p M \times T_p^\ast M \to \mathbb{R}$, where $(V, \omega) \mapsto \omega(V)$. This is essentially the fact that the double dual of a (nice) vector space is canonically isomorphic to the vector space. See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2870237/one-forms-are-dual-to-tangent-vectors?rq=1